# How to determine exact software version of an installed conda package?

Tags: python, conda

I would like to specify exact versions inside my conda environment file. I've installed the latest version available by adding an unversioned entry to my environment.yaml, followed by `conda env update`.

```
# environment.yaml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - r
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - gawk=4.2.1
  - plink # new package -- get the latest
```

Updated the environment with:

```
$ conda env update -n myenv -f environment.yaml
...
plink-1.90b4-h 100% |#################| Time: 0:00:00   1.63 MB/
```

A specific (latest) version "1.904b4-h" was pulled, but that seems truncated and doesn't reflect exactly a conda package version. How would I go about updating the environment with a version string that conda expects?

Answer (score 15):

One way I've found is to use `conda list` to produce a listing of all the packages contained in the environment (it can be optionally filtered to a specific package with `-f`, in this case "plink"):

```
$ conda list -n myenv -f plink --json
[
  {
    "base_url": null, 
    "build_number": 2, 
    "build_string": "h0a6d026_2", 
    "channel": "bioconda", 
    "dist_name": "plink-1.90b4-h0a6d026_2", 
    "name": "plink", 
    "platform": null, 
    "version": "1.90b4", 
    "with_features_depends": null
  }
]
```

You may omit the `--json` flag to get a simpler output, which is easier on the eyes but might require grepping/awk'ing:

```
$ conda list -n genomics-py36 -f plink
# packages in environment at /home/foo/envs/myenv:
#
plink                     1.90b4               h0a6d026_2    bioconda
```

*Note: For your scripts: `conda list` always exits with code 0, whether a package is found or not.*

Then you can modify the environment.yaml file with the exact version:

```yaml
# environment.yaml updated
channels:
  ...
dependencies:
  ...
  - plink=1.90b4
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `conda list | grep xxx` will solve your problem.

Given:
We need to check PyTorch version:

```
conda list | grep PyTorch

# Return
pytorch                   1.10.0          py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
torchaudio                0.10.0               py38_cu113    pytorch
torchvision               0.11.1               py38_cu113    pytorch
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `conda list`, just like `grep`, uses substring search on package names. So if you want to ensure you are getting the version of an exactly matched package name, then you need to obtain `conda list` results in JSON format and parse them with `jq`, e.g. thus - for `pandas`:

```
$ conda list pandas --json | jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="pandas") | .version'
1.5.3
```

... in an environment where there are 3 packages (installed with pip, which `conda list` also by default includes) containing the "pandas" substring in their names:

```
$ conda list pandas
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
geopandas                 0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pandas-profiling          3.6.6                    pypi_0    pypi
```